# The completion of a $\sigma$-algebra with respect to a finite measure $\mu$ is exactly the set of $\mu^*$-measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory

I am asked to show that if $(E, \mathcal E, \mu)$ is a measure space with $E \; \sigma$-finite, $\mu^*$ the associated outer measure to $\mu$ and with:

$\mathcal N = \{N \subset E \; \mid\; \exists B \in \mathcal E, \; N \subset B,\; \mu(B) = 0   \}$

$ \mathcal E ^\mu = \mathcal M = \{ A \cup N \; \mid \; A \in \mathcal E, \; N \in \mathcal N  \}$

Then $\mathcal E^\mu = \{ \mu^*\text{-measurable sets}\}$ where a set $A \subset E$ is said to be $\mu^*$-measurable if:

$\forall B \subset E, \;\;\mu^*(B) = \mu^*(B \cap A) + \mu^*(B \cap A^C)$

So far I have managed to show that $\mathcal E^\mu \subset \mathcal M$ and am trying to prove that $\mathcal M \subset \mathcal E^\mu$ so that I can conclude $\mathcal M = \mathcal E^\mu$, but I'm not convinced I've done it properly.

I have that:

$\forall A \in \mathcal M,\; \exists B \in \mathcal E$ such that $\mu^*(A) = \mu(B)$ and $A \subset B$

Letting $N = B\backslash A$,

$A \cup N = B \in \mathcal E \subset \mathcal E^\mu \Rightarrow \exists \;(A' \cup N') \in \mathcal E^\mu \text{ such that } A \cup N = A' \cup N'$

$\Rightarrow A = (A \cup N)\cap (A \cup N^C) = (A' \cup N') \cap (A \cup N^C)$

$ \Rightarrow A = (A' \cap(A \cup N^C))\cup(N' \cap(A\cup N^C))$

$A' \cap(A \cup N^C) \subset A' \in \mathcal E \text{ and } N' \cap(A\cup N^C) \ \subset N' \in \mathcal N \Rightarrow A \in \mathcal E^\mu$

$$\Rightarrow \mathcal M \subset \mathcal E^\mu$$

I suspect I might have gotten confused in all the intersections and unions or just in the logic of the argument itself. Is this a valid proof?